# Upstart and bash function names containing "-"

Tags: bash, shell, upstart

I inherited some bash scripts where the author used "-" in the function names instead of the more normal "_" e.g.:

```
function a-b {
...
}
```

Ugly but legal in bash. Problem is I sourced this inside an upstart script and got

> x.sh: line 5: `a-b': not a valid identifier

Took a while to realize it was the name and not the function contents. Anyway, renaming is not an easy option in this case and as I've learned, upstart uses `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash` to parse? run its scripts. Hence I guess this issue.

Any ideas on a workaround other than renaming?

If nothing else, at least I hope this question will warn others on the perils of odd bash coding styles and how they come back to bite you sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Upstart cookbook, [Changing the Default Shell](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#changing-the-default-shell). There are 3 options, the first 2 involve changing your default shell from `/bin/sh` to something else. But the 3rd option looks like it would solve your particular issue.

*excerpt*

> Use a "here document" (assuming your chosen shell supports them)
>   within the Job Configuration Files you wish to run with a different
>   shell:
>
> ```
> script
> /bin/bash <<EOT
>
> echo "Hi - I am running under the bash shell"
>
> date
>
> echo "and so am I :)"
>
> EOT
> end script
> ```

Comment: That my friend is insanely useful. Many thanks.

Comment: @NeilMcGill - Thanks for the Q and good luck!