# Shell valid function name characters

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, function

Using extended Unicode characters is (no-doubt) useful for many users.

Simpler shells (ash (busybox), dash) and ksh do fail with:

```
tést() { echo 34; }

tést
```

But [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [mksh](/questions/tagged/mksh), [lksh](/questions/tagged/lksh), and [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) seem to allow it.

I am aware that POSIX [valid function names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05) use this definition of [Names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231). That means this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

However, in the first link it is also said:

> An implementation may allow other characters in a function name as an extension.

The questions are:

- Is this accepted and documented?
- Where?
- For which shells (if any)?

---

Related questions:
[Its possible use special characters in a shell function name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192393/79743)
I am not interested in using meta-characters (>) in function names.

[Upstart and bash function names containing “-”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151712/79743)
I do not believe that an operator (subtraction "-") should be part of a name.

Comment: you might find `alias` to be a tad more lenient. and so you can write the function with a some proper, buttoned-down name, and then just define a more stylishly named alias to call the function. in `dash` there is also some stuff you can do with `$PATH` and `%func`.

Comment: Definition of [Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) and [Alias Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_10)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since POSIX documentation allow it as an extension, there's nothing prevent implementation from that behavior.

A simple check (ran in `zsh`):

```sh
$ for shell in /bin/*sh 'busybox sh'; do
    printf '[%s]\n' $shell
    $=shell -c 'á() { :; }'
  done
[/bin/ash]
/bin/ash: 1: Syntax error: Bad function name
[/bin/bash]
[/bin/dash]
/bin/dash: 1: Syntax error: Bad function name
[/bin/ksh]
[/bin/lksh]
[/bin/mksh]
[/bin/pdksh]
[/bin/posh]
/bin/posh: á: invalid function name
[/bin/yash]
[/bin/zsh]
[busybox sh]
sh: syntax error: bad function name
```

show that `bash`, `zsh`, `yash`, `ksh93` (which `ksh` linked to in my system), `pdksh` and its derivation allow multi-bytes characters as function name.

`yash` [is designed to support multibyte characters](http://yash.osdn.jp/doc/_printf.html#notes) from the beginning, so there's no surprise it worked.

The other documentation you can refer is `ksh93`:

> A  blank  is  a  tab  or a space.  An identifier is a sequence of
>   letters, digits, or underscores starting with a letter or
>          underscore.  Identifiers are used as components of variable names.  A vname is a sequence of one or more identifiers  separated  by  a  .  and  optionally preceded by a ..  Vnames are used as function and variable names.  A word is a sequence of
>          characters from **the character set defined by the current locale**, excluding non-quoted metacharacters.

So setting to `C` locale:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ á() { echo 1; }
ksh: á: invalid function name
```

make it failed.

Comment: `posh`isn't worth to be listed in such a list. It depends on Linux specific bugs in `libc` and will not work on other platforms.

Comment: I cannot repeat your claims about `ksh93` using a self compiled ksh93 from original sources. While `ksh88` seems to accept non-7-Bit-ASCII letters for function names, only the `ksh93` binary from Ubuntu seems to accept them.

Comment: @schily ksh I used in this test is the binary in Debian (so it may be the same with one on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 12):

Note that functions share the same namespace as other commands including commands in the file system, which on most systems have no limitation on the characters or even bytes they may contain in their path.

So while most shells restrict the characters of their functions, there's no real good reason why they would do that. That means in those shells, there are commands you can't replace with a function.

`zsh` and `rc` allow anything for their function names including some with `/` and the empty string. `zsh` even allows NUL bytes.

```
$ zsh
$ $'\0'() echo nul
$ ^@
nul
$ ""() uname
$ ''
Linux
$ /bin/ls() echo test
$ /bin/ls
test
```

A simple command in shell is a list of arguments, and the first argument is used to derive the command to execute. So, it's just logical that those arguments and function names share the same possible values and in `zsh` arguments to builtins and functions can be any byte sequence.

There's not security issue here as the functions *you* (the script author) define are the ones *you* invoke.

Where there may be security issues is when the parsing is affected by the environment, for instance with shells where the valid names for functions is affected by the locale.

Comment: One may play games in bash too, starting with `function /bin/sh { echo "$0: $FUNCNAME: Permission denied"; return 126; }`, and potentially useful things too with functions named `--`, `//`, `@` or `%` etc.

Comment: but dont shells tend to bypass a hash-table lookup when `/` is found in a name? and a function isnt just an executable name - its code. i would think a simple implementation could encounter a lot of parse problems if its stored function names included metacharacters.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the inability of bash to contain nulls in vars, that could be reasonably extended to function names. I do not have an specific example, but I do feel that this games of allowing almost anything for names is more of a potential security breach than an "easy way to work". I hope I am wrong.