# How to test if array elements are all equal in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, array

The following array represented the numbers of disks on each linux machines

Each **single array** includes the number of disks on a **linux machine**.

```
echo ${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[*]}
4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4
```

what is the simple way to identify that all array's values are equal?

Good status:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Bad status:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 2 4
```

Bad status:

```
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 2 6 2
```

Comment: So many answers and no votes?

Comment: Will this only be testing integers or should it also test strings?

Comment: I just waiting for the best answer dont worry soon I will vote

Comment: I meant everyone else.  This question deserves upvote IMO.

Comment: once you need something of at least this level of complexity, it's a good time to start using a real programming language, until it's too late…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bash` + GNU `sort` + GNU `grep` solution:

```bash
if [ "${#array[@]}" -gt 0 ] && [ $(printf "%s\000" "${array[@]}" | 
       LC_ALL=C sort -z -u |
       grep -z -c .) -eq 1 ] ; then
  echo ok
else
  echo bad
fi
```

English explanation: if unique-sorting the elements of the array results in only one element, then print "ok".  Otherwise print "bad".

The array is printed with NUL bytes separating each element, piped into GNU sort (relying on the `-z` aka `--zero-terminated` and `-u` aka `--unique` options), and then into `grep` (using options `-z` aka `--null-data` and `-c` aka `--count`) to count the output lines.

Unlike my previous version, I can't use `wc` here because it requires input lines terminated with a newline...and using `sed` or `tr` to convert NULs to newlines after the `sort` would defeat the purpose of using NUL separators.  `grep -c` makes a reasonable substitute.

---

Here's the same thing rewritten as a function:

```bash
function count_unique() {
  local LC_ALL=C

  if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] ; then 
    echo 0
  else
    echo "$(printf "%s\000" "$@" |
              sort --zero-terminated --unique |
              grep --null-data --count .)"
  fi
}



ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4)

if [ "$(count_unique "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}")" -eq 1 ] ; then
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "bad"
fi
```

Comment: Note that `sort -u` doesn't return unique elements but one of each set of elements that sort the same. For instance, it would say "ok" on `ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(① ②)` on a GNU systems where locales typically decide those 2 characters sort the same. You'd want `LC_ALL=C sort -u` for byte-to-byte uniqueness.

Comment: just another note it will be fail  also in case no additional disks are appears from CLI  so need also to add this syntax

Comment: [[ ` printf "%s\n" "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}" | wc -l ` -eq ` printf "%s\n" "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}" | grep -c "0" ` ]] && echo fail

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the locale issue is worth dealing with, as is the IFS issue.  Testing for an empty list is, IMO, best done separately - there's no need to check for non-unique elements in an empty set.

Comment: Hi Cas I prefer your previous answer

Comment: feel free to use my original answer if it works for you, but the issues @StéphaneChazelas raised aren't just pedantry - they can cause weird (and serious) problems in some circumstances.  If you're 100% confident that they don't apply to your array (and with the sample you've shown, there should be no problem), then it'll be fine....but I prefer to post a generic answer that is safe to use for many similar tasks than one that has lots of hidden assumptions that could result in breakage.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I am sure you know this, however it deserves pointing out explicitly, that *that is the correct result*. When asking whether all elements of a collection have a certain property, then the answer is always "yes" for the empty collection. This is basically a *vacuous truth*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I'd expect more people, when asked _are all your antlers soft?_ (to keep the Christmassy note) would answer _I don't have any antler_. Few would say _yes_ (I'd expect a few would say _no_). IOW, an empty set is a special case, there is no _correct_ or _incorrect_ outcome. I was just pointing it out.

Answer (score 9):

With `zsh`:

```
if ((${#${(u)ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}} == 1)); then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

Where `(u)` is a parameter expansion flag to expand *unique* values. So we're getting a count of the unique values in the array.

Replace `== 1` with `<= 1` is you want to consider an empty array is OK.

With `ksh93`, you could sort the array and check that the  first element is the same as the last:

```
set -s -- "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
if [ "$1" = "${@: -1}" ]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

With ksh88 or pdksh/mksh:

```
set -s -- "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
if eval '[ "$1" = "${'"$#"'}" ]'; then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

With `bash`, you'd probably need a loop:

```
unique_values() {
  typeset i
  for i do
    [ "$1" = "$i" ] || return 1
  done
  return 0
}
if unique_values "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"; then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

(would work with all the Bourne-like shells with array support (ksh, zsh, bash, yash)).

Note that it returns OK for an empty array. Add a `[ "$#" -gt 0 ] || return` at the start of the function if you don't want that.

Comment: all these answers not seems to support bash ?

Comment: @yael, see edit for a bash solution. But why would you use `bash`?

Comment: In Bash, the help page for `typeset` says ```Obsolete.  See `help declare'.``` Is there a reason you're using it instead of `local` or `declare`?

Comment: @wjandrea `typeset` is the one that works in all 4 shells. It's also the _original_ one from ksh in the early 80s (  bash mostly copied ksh88 when it comes to variable scoping type setting and declaration but decided to rename `typeset` `declare` and make `typeset` an alias to declare).

Answer (score 4):

**`bash`** + **`awk`** soltion:

```
function get_status() {
    arr=("$@")    # get the array passed as argument
    if awk 'v && $1!=v{ exit 1 }{ v=$1 }' <(printf "%d\n" "${arr[@]}"); then 
        echo "status: Ok"
    else 
        echo "status: Bad"
    fi
}
```

---

Test case #1:

```
ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(4 4 4 4 4 2 4 4)
get_status "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
status: Bad
```

---

Test case #2:

```
ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4)
get_status "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
status: Ok
```

Answer (score 4):

I have another bash only solution that should work with strings as well:

```
isarray.equal () {
    local placeholder="$1"
    local num=0
    while (( $# )); do
        if [[ "$1" != "$placeholder" ]]; then
            num=1
            echo 'Bad' && break
        fi
        shift
    done
    [[ "$num" -ne 1 ]] && echo 'Okay'
}
```

Demonstration:

```
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4)
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# isarray.equal "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
Bad
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4)
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# isarray.equal "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
Okay
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(four four four four two four four four)
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# isarray.equal "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
Bad
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# ARRAY_DISK_Quantity=(four four four four four four four four)
[root@JBSTEST001 ~]# isarray.equal "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
Okay
```

Comment: Note that dots are not valid in function names, though Bash is pretty permissive. This may cause issues like in exporting the function.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245953/237982

Answer (score 2):

With bash and GNU grep:

```
if grep -qE '^([0-9]+)( \1)*$' <<< "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"; then 
  echo "okay"
else
  echo "not okay"
fi
```

Comment: Yes, but what about (10 10 10 10)? Otherwise, quite nice.

Comment: @Joe: Good catch. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

bash only solution (assuming `a` is `ARRAY_DISK_Quantity`)

```
ttt=${a[0]}
res=0
for i in "${a[@]}"
do 
    let res+=$(if [ "$ttt" -ne "$i" ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi);  
done
if [ "$res" -eq 0 ]
then 
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "bad"
fi
```

Comment: Works, but counts all errors when just one is enough: `if [ "$ttt" -ne "$i" ]; then res=1; break; fi; `

Answer (score 0):

Here is POSIX Awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while (++z < ARGC) if (ARGV[z] != ARGV[1]) exit 1}' "${ARRAY_DISK_Quantity[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to compare each array element to the next. End the loop one iteration less than the length of the array to avoid comparing the last element to nothing at the end.

```
for (( i=0; i<((${#array[@]}-1)); i++ )); do
    [ "${array[$i]}" != "${array[(($i+1))]}" ] && echo "Mismatch"
done
echo "Match"
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L and thank you for your contribution!
This code will print "Match" even if a mismatch is found... is it intended?